# How to avoid loading Active Directory for every element in array in Flask

Tags: flask, active-directory, subprocess

I have an array and for every element in array I need to call

`subprocess.check_output(['powershell','-Command',query])`

My array size s 20k+ and for every element above query takes 12 seconds to respond which is very expensive.
I check my powershell for every query it show Loading Active Directory with module AD

Can anyone please help me to know what to do to optimize this